# Не получается зациклить код

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я хочу написать код с функциями (которые имеют несколько элементов) и зациклить его, и сделать так чтобы из каждой функции брали по одному элементу и использовали дальше в коде

```
# Функция
def tarif_type (tarif_type_menu):
    tarif1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"body[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[{tarif_type_menu}]")
    tarif1.click()

# Элементы
tarif_type(1)
tarif_type(2)

time.sleep(1)

day = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='el-radio-group'])[1]/label[2]")
day.click()

time.sleep(1)
days12456 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//input[@class='el-input__inner'])[3]")
days12456.click()

time.sleep(1)

# Функция
def days (days_number):
    days1234 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"(//ul[@class='el-scrollbar__view el-select-dropdown__list'])[5]//li[@class='el-select-dropdown__item'][{days_number}]")
    days1234.click()

# Элементы
days(1)
days(2)
days(3)
days(4)
days(5)
```

Comment: начни здесь: [ask]

Comment: хорошо, спасибо